# Why is '.NULL' added in the end of the paste output?

Tags: r

I have been trying to access a particular column which is user given from a data frame. For that purpose I've used the 'paste' function to concatenate the user given parameter 'outcome'. Now, the outcome can have three possible values i.e. 'heart attack','heart failure','pneumonia'. My purpose is to capitalise the first letter of the input and then paste it to the column name to complete it.

```
rankhospital <- function(outcome) {

  # Here the outcome can be  c('heart attack','heart failure','pneumonia')
  b <- strsplit(outcome,' ') # For the two outcomes that have a space in between i.e. 'heart attack' & 'heart failure', I need to capitalise each of the first letter.
  c <- b[1]
  d <- b[2]
# If the outcome is 'pneumonia' then the d variable will be NULL
  if (!is.null(d)){
    e <- paste(toupper(substr(c, 1, 1)), substr(c, 2, nchar(c)), sep="")
    f <- paste(toupper(substr(d, 1, 1)), substr(d, 2, nchar(d)), sep="")
    g <- paste("Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.",e,".",f,sep='')
  }
  else{
    e <- paste(toupper(substr(c, 1, 1)), substr(c, 2, nchar(c)), sep="")
    g <- paste("Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.",e,sep='')
  }
  g
}
```

For 'pneumonia' as an outcome, I get an output like: "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia.NULL"
Due to this .NULL in the end I cannot access this column and it always returns NULL

For 'heart attack' or 'heart failure', the output is something like:
"Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.C(\"heart\", \"attack\").NULL"
Over here I cannot seem to understand why didn't it even capitalise the letters

Comment: You should be using `b <- strsplit(outcome,' ')[[1]]`. `strsplit` will return a list equal to the length of the input, not a simple vector.

Comment: I did this but for outcome as 'pneumonia' the output shows:  "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia.NANA"